# How to make column whole page high?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make the column border to reach the footer as in an example[image]
It should work in these two variants:

[short variant](http://www.automatydrzwiowe.pl/trunk/index.php?event=article&parent_id=3&menu_id=1)

[high variant](http://www.automatydrzwiowe.pl/trunk/index.php?module=guest&class=welcome&event=product&parent_id=104&menu_id=2)

Thanks !

What do you think about min-height: 430px; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a background image that is 1 pixel high and contains a very thin horizontal strip of the background + line(s) that you'd like to have, repeated on the y-axis:

```
#centered_container { background: url(i/bg.png) 50% repeat-y; }
```

Since your site seems to be centered, use `50%` to center the background image as well.

Comment: I think it is a little more explanatory to wrap the layout in the container with the background. With a tiny margin, both sides can still be individually styled while letting the dividing line show through.

Comment: there's no need for this, imo.

Comment: @yoda: An your alternative is?

Comment: @Ates Goral: I had already answered. Since the central container is always (or at least it seems to be) larger than the left container ..

Comment: @yoda: I don't think that can be guaranteed. That's just an assumption.

Comment: @Ates Goral: Same goes for your sugestion. Using percentage on the background when the website seems to be build on a fixrd layout .. Anyway, best of both worlds would probably be a master container with dynamic height and a background, sort of like you stated.

Comment: @yoda: If the website has a fixed width and is centered, making the background image the same width and centering it with 50% simply works. There's a reason this method is widely employed.

Comment: @yoda: Even if the image is not centered 50% but instead at another value, if you attach the dividing image to the background it will _always_ be the height of the longest column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a technique that requires no JavaScript and works in a cross-platform manner. It will require a reworking of your css.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-left-menu.htm